# Looking for 2D turn-based rpg game which can run on windows xp

Tags: windows, game, rpg

I'm looking for 2D turn-based rpg game which can run on windows xp (The Machine is an old Intel "Wolfdale" Dual-Core CPU E5400 with 2 GB of RAM with an integrated graphics chipset (G33) with 2 GB RAM). Bonus points if it has open-world thingie, not linear gameplay.

Answer (score 1):

it is not easy to recommend something because of the few requirements (for the game itself) you made, but i'll try...

you should definitely try [**The Battle for Wesnoth**](https://www.wesnoth.org/) (a free, turn-based tactical strategy game):

- it should work on machines with at least 1 GHz and 512 MB RAM
- it is foss (GPLv2) and cross platform available: https://wiki.wesnoth.org/Download
- multilingual translated into 50+ languages
- features single-player, and online/hotseat multiplayer combat
- hundreds of campaign scenarios available for download through a simple in-game dialog

maybe also have a look at [**Freeciv**](http://www.freeciv.org/) or [**FreeCol**](http://www.freecol.org/), but i haven't tried them myself so i will only mention that they fit your (hardware-)requirements.

---

*personal notes:*

- *i just recommended free (foss) games, so you can try them without a hassle yourself and if you don't like them you haven't misspent your money. - for sure if you like foss it will be welcome to support the project by donating some money you like to spend.*
- *i really like strategy games in general (mostly not turn-based) but usually i don't like the whole fantasy-stuff and although i really like wesnoth.*